# Can't override opCmp and opEquals of a struct

Tags: d, dmd

From D's [documentation](http://dlang.org/operatoroverloading.html#equals):

> Alternatively you can declare a single templated opEquals function with an auto ref parameter:
>
> ```
> bool opEquals()(auto ref S s) { ... }
> ```
>
> <...>
>
> If structs declare an opCmp member function, it should follow the following form:
>
> ```
> int opCmp(ref const S s) const { ... }
> ```

Why does the following code fail to compile, then?

```
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;

struct Fgs {
    int v;
    this(int iv) {
        v = iv;
    }

    bool opEquals()(auto ref Fgs another) {
        return v == another.v;
    }

    int opCmp(ref const Fgs another) const {
        if (this == another) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.v < another.v) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}


unittest {
    auto a = Fgs(42);
    auto b = Fgs(10);
    assert(a != b);
    assert(a > b);
}
```

Here'd DMD's output:

```
/home/mfag/lighthouse/testss.d(15): Error: template testss.Fgs.opEquals does not match any function template declaration
/home/mfag/lighthouse/testss.d(10): Error: template testss.Fgs.opEquals() cannot deduce template function from argument types !()(const(Fgs))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` wasn't taken into account when that was written. This should work:

```
bool opEquals()(auto const ref Fgs another) const
```

But this is an area of the language that's a bit in a state of flux, using `auto ref` might be possible on non-templates in the future.